# Splitting an Array into multiple chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to find a way to split an array into a set number of chunks. I've seen multiple posts on here which split it into chunks with a specified length, but that's not what I'm after. For example, consider the following array:

`var array = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']`

I would like to easily be able to pass this to a function such as the following

`splitArray(array, 2)`

Which would result in the following:

`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`

Edit: As i mentioned, I wasnt to evenly split an array into a set number of chunks, not a number of chunks with a specified length as other questions ask

Comment: Does this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Comment: You should make an attempt to solve this on your own before posting the question. We're here to fix existing code, not provide you with it from scratch.

Comment: The main problem here isn't necessarily spiting the array into chunks, rather determining what size of chunks you want and how to approach possible leftovers or array length not conforming.

Comment: No, that splits it into the amount if items. For example `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` gets split into 5 arrays of 2 items, I want to split it into 2 arrays of 5 items

Comment: @Santi my apologies. I'm more looking for the logic of the idea so I can then build a function

Comment: @lix thanks, this is the kind of thing I was after, just needed a hand with the logic side of things

Comment: Agree with @santi , I just tumbled upon a question where someone is asking for help in her assignment.

Comment: @G.Hanson which simply means you need to divide the length of the source array by 2 (or the number of chunks you want) to get chunk size before passing it into the chunking function. still a dupe.